# ember-table even odd color strip

Tags: ember.js, ember-table

I get stuck while adding even/odd color strips to table rows in [ember-table](http://addepar.github.io/ember-table/#/financial).

Regular CSS selector `:even` `:odd` won't work because the lazy table will reusing existing limited number of row elements, so the first element in DOM may not be the first row on screen nor array of data.

Did anyone solve this issue before?

Comment: the link in my post is ember-table example page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do that.

In Table class, rows property

```
rows: Ember.computed(function() {
  var root = this.get(&#39;root&#39;);
  if (!root) {
    return Ember.A();
  }
  var rows = this.flattenTree(null, root, Ember.A());
  this.computeStyles(null, root);

  // start of modification
  // now each row has an 'isShowing' boolean flag
  // _.rest is underscore function to skip the first element
  // (in my case it is an empty TableRow instance)
  _.rest(rows).filterProperty('isShowing').forEach(function (row, i) {
    row.set('evenOdd', (i % 2 === 0) ? 'even' : 'odd');
  });
  // end of modification

  var maxGroupingLevel = Math.max.apply(rows.getEach('groupingLevel'));
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    return row.computeRowStyle(maxGroupingLevel);
  });
  return rows;
}).property('root'),
```

In Row class `computedRowStyle` method

```
computeRowStyle: function(maxLevels) {
  var level = this.getFormattingLevel(this.get(&#39;groupingLevel&#39;), maxLevels);
  // start of modifications
  var evenOdd = this.get('evenOdd');
  this.set('rowStyle', 'ember-table-row-style-%@ ember-row-evenodd-%@'.fmt(level, evenOdd));
  // end of modifications
},
```

Whatever value set in `rowStyle` will be shown in row element class, so only need to add two more styles in CSS   `ember-row-evenodd-even` and `ember-row-evenodd-odd`